# Convergence, continuity and derivative of series of functions. Abbott 2ed. 6.4.6

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification, self-learning

I am working on exercise 6.4.6. from Abbott's Understanding Analysis 2nd ed. The statement is the following:

> Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{1}{x+3}+\frac{1}{x+4}-\dots.$
>
> Show $f$ is defined for all $x>0$. Is $f$ continuous on $(0,\infty)$? How about differentiable?

**My solution**:

We know that the alternating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ converges. We can also write the sum of the statement as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x+n-1}$, and use $f_{n}(x)$ for a specific term of the series.

a) If $x>1$, the series $f$ differs by a positive number in the denominator, so every series term is smaller than every term of the alternating series and hence would converge.

If $x\in(0,1)$, then after $n=2$ we have the same as above, and for $n=1$, we are just adding a constant term to the series, giving us a convergent series.

*Combining these results, we have that the series of the statement converges uniformly.*

b) Combining uniform convergence and the fact that for a specific $n$, $f_{n}(x)$ is continuous, we have that by the term-by-term continuity theorem, $f(x)$ is continuous.

c) If we take the derivative of $f_{n}(x)$ for a specific $n$ we get: $f_{n}'(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(x+n-1)^{2}}$. Performing a similar analysis as in a), we have that the series of derivatives converges uniformly, and conclude that $f(x)$ is differentiable by the term-by-term differentiatiability theorem.

I would be grateful if you check whether my solution is correct. In particular, I am a bit doubtful of the conclusion in italics in part a). The problem I see is that I cannot use Weierstrass M-test directly because of the alternating nature of the series I am comparing with.

Comment: *How* does uniform convergence follows from what's written before the sentence in italics?

Comment: Intuitively, I am summing terms that are almost all (with the exception of n=1) smaller than the terms of the alternating harmonic series. But I can't seem to find a formal way of proving it. :(

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3971633/42969

Comment: @MartinR, you are right, this is a duplicate, I searched for a bit but I didn't find anything. Apologies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuity of $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{x+n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971633/continuity-of-fx-sum-n-0-infty-1n-frac1xn) – Found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%2B1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%2B2%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%2B3%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%2B4%7D-%5Cdots.%24)

Comment: @MartinR I just worked through their solution and I believe I got a better understanding of it. I wasn't aware of the tool. Thanks for the pointer.